# How do I add event listeners to dynamically created HTML list elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to make a to-do list application where when a clicked, a list element toggles to a class `checked` that adds a strikethrough style. I'm having trouble targeting one list element at a time and not checking off the whole list. How can I dynamically add event listeners for each item? Currently, with the below code, items added are already checked and I cannot figure out why.

My HTML appears as follows:

```
<div id="body">
            <form id="form" onsubmit="newElement()" target="_self">
                <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="What's on the agenda?">
            </form>

            <ul id="list">
                <li class = "checked">test</li >
            </ul>
        </div>
```

My function grabs data from a text box through this function

```
function newElement() {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop default redirect

    /* create a list item and put the inputted text within */
    var li = document.createElement("li"); // create a list item
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("task").value; // value of text box
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue); // create a text node of the box value
    li.appendChild(t); // put the text node in the li
    li.addEventListener('click', checkToggle(li)); // add event listener for a click to toggle
                                                   // a strikethrough

    /* append the li item to the ul */
    appendItem("list", li); 
}
```

and then the `checkToggle` function appears as follows

```
/* make items get checked when clicked */
function checkToggle(li) {
    li.classList.toggle("checked");
}
```

However, when the page is loaded, **every element is automatically checked when added already.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing function - `checkToggle(li)`

You should attach function like
`addEventListener('click', checkToggle)` without parenthesis

```js
function newElement() {
event.preventDefault(); // stop default redirect

/* create a list item and put the inputted text within */
var li = document.createElement("li"); // create a list item
var inputValue = document.getElementById("task").value; // value of text box
var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue); // create a text node of the box value
li.appendChild(t); // put the text node in the li
li.addEventListener('click', checkToggle); // add event listener for a click to toggle
                                               // a strikethrough

/* append the li item to the ul */
document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(li);
}

function checkToggle() {
this.classList.toggle("checked");
}
```

```css
.checked{color: blue;}
```

```html
<div id="body">
        <form id="form" onsubmit="newElement()" target="_self">
            <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="What's on the agenda?">
        </form>

        <ul id="list">
            <li class = "checked">test</li >
        </ul>
    </div>
```